# ASP.NET Core Entity Framework code-to-database scaffolding not recognizing Id property or [Key] annotation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-code-first-mapping, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I'm trying to scaffold out a razor page set for my `Ticket` class and I'm getting an error when Entity Framework tries to create the database:

[image: This shows the error next to my "Ticket" definition which includes a Key annotation above an "Id" property]

My understanding is that if you have a property "Id" it will use it, and if you set the [Key] annotation it will specifically tell Entity Framework to use that property. I have both of those things, so what gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your properties public .

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```